# If $\varphi$ is bounded above, increasing, and concave down, does $x\varphi'(x)$ go to zero? How fast?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\varphi: [0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,1)$ is an increasing differentiable function ($C^\infty$ if you want) with $\varphi \rightarrow 1$ and $\varphi'>0, \varphi''<0$.  **My question is: Is it true that $$\limsup_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{{\color{blue}{x\varphi'(x)}}}{\color{green}{1-\varphi(x)}}\leq 1~~~, \text{or even} < \infty~~?$$**  If not, and you see some additional hypotheses on $\varphi$ that make it true, that would also be welcome.

[image]

In fact, I'm even having trouble proving $x\phi'(x)\rightarrow 0$, even though it seems obvious from the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, for $x > 0,$
$$ \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) \rightarrow 0.  $$
The Mean Value Theorem says 
$$ \frac{ \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x)}{2x - x} = \varphi'(\xi) $$ with
$$ x < \xi < 2x. $$
So
$$  \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) = x  \varphi'(\xi) .  $$
Since $ \xi < 2x$ and negative second derivative, $  \varphi'(\xi) >  \varphi'(2x), $ and
 $$  \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) = x  \varphi'(\xi) >   x  \varphi'(2x).  $$
Since $ \varphi(2x) - \varphi(x) \rightarrow 0,  $
$$   x  \varphi'(2x)  \rightarrow 0, $$ also
$$  2 x  \varphi'(2x)  \rightarrow 0, $$ finally 
$$  t  \varphi'(t)  \rightarrow 0. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \varphi(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{(1+x)^n} $$

Your limit is $n,$ bigger than the $1$ you allow.

Next I will try for $\infty$

This works,
$$ \varphi(x) = 1 - e^{-x} $$

Comment: Hi Will, do you mean this as a counter example? It looks like $x\phi'(x)/(1-\phi(x)$ goes to 1?

Comment: @Timkinsella fixed it

Comment: Thanks, Will. Do you know whether $x\phi'(x)$ has to go to zero?